# Unable to correctly verify Slack requests

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, slack

I'm in the process of building a Slack bot using the events API as an experiment for work. I'm currently having problems verifying the request and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The bot is implemented using Typescript/Node/AWS Lambda/API Gateway. The code I'm using to verify looks like this

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto';

export const validateSlackRequest = (
  requestSignature: string,
  signingSecret: string,
  timestamp: string,
  body: string, 
) => {
    
  const baseString = `v0:${timestamp}:${body}`;
  const signature = 'v0=' + crypto.createHmac('sha256', signingSecret)
                                  .update(baseString).digest('hex');

  if (!crypto.timingSafeEqual(Buffer.from(requestSignature, 'utf8'), Buffer.from(signature, 'utf8'))) {
    throw new Error('Slack request verification failed');
  }
};
```

Where `body` is simply the `event.body` property passed to the lambda, verbatim. At the present time, the unit tests I've written around this pass when I use the data from the Slack tutorial [here](https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack), but fail when I locally substitute in data from real requests.

I've been using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@rajat_sriv/verifying-requests-from-slack-using-node-js-69a8b771b704) to base my code around. What's confusing to me is that the tutorial seems to suggest I should convert the body to a querystring format before using it as my basestring, despite the Slack documentation saying nothing about this, and saying "Use the raw request body, before it has been deserialized from JSON or other forms.".

Comment: Are you using the http body or the slack event body?

Comment: I’m using the raw request body

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of how to verify a Slack request, it also supports slash commands:

| Slack bot event example | [<kbd>Run in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-70653161) |
| --- | --- |

```js
  import crypto from 'crypto';
  import formurlencoded from 'form-urlencoded';

  export const validateSlackRequest = (
    requestSignature: string,
    timestampHeader: string, // Get it from the request header x-slack-request-timestamp
    contentType: string, // Get it from the request header content-type
    signingSecret: string,
    timestamp: string,
    body: string,
  ) => {
      
    let rawBody;
    if (contentType?.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
      // Slash commands are sent in this content type
      rawBody = formurlencoded(body);
    } else {
      rawBody = JSON.stringify(body)
        .replace(/\//g, '\\/')
        .replace(/[\u007f-\uffff]/g, (c) => '\\u' + ('0000' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4));
    }

    const basestring = ['v0', timestampHeader, rawBody].join(':');
    const calculatedSignature = 'v0=' + crypto.createHmac('sha256', signingSecret).update(basestring).digest('hex');
    const calculatedSignatureBuffer = Buffer.from(calculatedSignature, 'utf8');
    const requestSignatureBuffer = Buffer.from(requestSignature, 'utf8');
    return crypto.timingSafeEqual(calculatedSignatureBuffer, requestSignatureBuffer);
  };
```